# Errors in API Analytics with API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am setting up WSO2 APIM with Analytics running on docker. I am getting the following error in the worker & no data is being published to the console. I'm using a MySQL database.

I am using the docker images @ `https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/tree/v2.6.0.3/dockerfiles/centos`

- OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_8u222b10
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar

```
[2019-10-05 04:58:27,208] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker} - Dropping wrongly formatted event sent org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: Error when converting org.wso2.metrics.stream.Gauge:1.0.0 of event bundle with events 4
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:188)
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.toEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:90)
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: No StreamDefinition for streamId org.wso2.metrics.stream.Gauge:1.0.0 present in cache
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:171)
... 7 more
```

Comment: can you share your event format and the stream definition?

Comment: @JorgeInfanteOsorio Where would I find that information?

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when the particular stream, "org.wso2.metrics.stream.Gauge:1.0.0", hasn't deployed properly from the capp. Below steps can be followed to resolve this.

1. Remove the /tmp directory which is available in the APIM_ANALYTICS_HOME directory.
2. Restart the server.
3. If there is any issue observed while deploying the capp, please backup the capp and remove it from the carbon console. (You can find it under the fault apps section. This is to remove any cache data related to the capp).
4. Then follow steps 1 and 2 again.